# How to add optional file to Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I have this in my Makefile:

```
VERSION=0.10.2
SED=sed

www/Makefile: www/Makefile.in Makefile .$(VERSION)
    test -d www && $(SED) -e "s/{{VERSION}}/$(VERSION)/g" www/Makefile.in > www/Makefile || true
```

to update Makefile in www directory but my repo on github don't have that directory it's only on my local drive, when I call it after cloning the repo I've got error that there are not rules to make www/Makefile.in

how can I make this work when there are no www/Makefile.in file?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but what do you want Make to do if there is no `www/Makiefile.in`?

Comment: @Beta just ignore that fact and continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make this work when there are no www/Makefile.in file?

To workaround the similar situation I use the `$(wildcard)` function. Officially, the function is used to expand the shell glob wildcards, but it also checks for the file/directory availability. Important: if file/dir doesn't exist, the `$(wildcard)` returns empty string.

For example, remove the `www/Makefile.in` from prereq list if it doesn't exist:

```
www/Makefile: $(wildcard www/Makefile.in) Makefile .$(VERSION)
    test -d www && $(SED) -e "s/{{VERSION}}/$(VERSION)/g" www/Makefile.in > www/Makefile || true
```

Alternatively, disable the rule altogether if the `www` directory doesn't exist:

```
ifneq (,$(wildcard www))
www/Makefile: www/Makefile.in Makefile .$(VERSION)
    test -d www && $(SED) -e "s/{{VERSION}}/$(VERSION)/g" www/Makefile.in > www/Makefile || true
endif
```

Comment: First solution work the second throw error that there are not rules for www/Makefile if www is missing.

Comment: If second doesn't work, that means that you have somewhere dependency on the `www/Makefile`. You could also try to remove/make optional the dependency there, e.g. `$(if $(wildcard www),www/Makefile)`. Good luck.